# In a certain city, 46% of the people (adults) classify themselves as independent..probability

Tags: probability

I don't know how to solve this question.
I would appreciate any help.

In a certain city, 46% of the people (adults) classify themselves as independent, 30% classify themselves as liberals, and 24% as conservatives. In a recent election, 35% of the independent people voted, 62% of the liberals voted, and 58% of the conservatives voted.
(a) What is the probability that a random person voted in the election?
(b) Given that a person voted in the election, what is the probability that he/she is a liberal?

Comment: Depending on your style of course, the problem is solved by using a tree diagram, or by a calculation that involves symbols that look like $\Pr(A|B)$. (These are called *conditional* probabilities.) If you indicate the style you have seen, potential answerers can use the style that you are expected to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple probability question without any "tricks." Since we are dealing with percents, lets think about it the easy way - with a city of 100 people.
There are 46 Is, 30 Ls and 24 Cs. Of these, .35*46 voted, .62*30 voted, and .58*24 voted. Note that percents are essentially fractions out of 100. So 62% corresponds to 0.62. We multiply because the probabilities are stated that way. The keyword "of," usually denotes multiplication. We want a fraction/part/percent of the whole (though the whole in this case is itself a part of the whole) so me multiply.

So the total number of people to vote is .35*46 + .62*30 + .58*24 = 48.62
$\textbf{So 48.62% chance of voting.}$

Now we want to know that if you voted, are you a liberal? Well, 48.62 people voted, and of these, .62*30 = 18.6 were liberals. So there is a 18.6/48.62 = .38... chance of being liberal. $\textbf{38.35...%}$

Does that explain clearly enough, or do you need/want more gaps filled in. Hope this helped.

Comment: No problem. By the way, if you are dealing with a more complicated problem, my approach above might not be as helpful as the more formulaic way presented in the other answer. But for something with only a handful of "moving parts," taking a nice slow walk through it as i did above, hopefully offers some insight. Basically, people generalized the ideas above to "conditional probability."

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ represent the independents. Let $L$ represent the liberals, and let $C$ represent the conservatives. We are given $P(I) = 0.46, P(L) = 0.3, P(C) = 0.24$.

**(a)**

If $35\%$ of independents voted, then $35\%$ of $46\%$ of people voted. Similarly for the remaining two classes, and since there is no overlap between the three, you can sum the three products. By the way, call this sum $V$, which is the probability someone voted, as we will use this in part (b).

**(b)**

You will need to use conditional probability. We write "the probability of $A$ given $B$" as $P(A\vert B)$ and it is equal to the probability of A and B together, divided by the probability of $B$ (since we are living in the universe where we know $B$ already happened). In symbolic form we write:
$$
P(A\vert B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$

One other point is that we can find the probability of A and B happening by looking at the conditional probability of $B$ given $A$ times the probability of $A$. This is because:
$$
\begin{align}
P(B\vert A) &= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}\\
P(B\vert A)P(A) &= P(A\cap B)
\end{align}
$$

Now, the question asks, "given that a person voted in the election, what is the probability that he/she is a liberal." In symbolic form this is asking for $P(L\vert V)$. What we **do** know is $P(L)$, $P(V\vert L)$, *and* $P(V)$. The first two are given in the question, and the last is from (a). So, fill in the numbers for the following equation:
$$
\begin{align}
P(L\vert V) &= \frac{P(L\cap V)}{P(V)}\\
&=\frac{P(V\cap L)}{P(V)}\\
&=\frac{P(V\vert L)P(L)}{P(V)}\Leftarrow\textrm{You know this}\\
\end{align}
$$